# Line Integral: $\int_C{x^2}\:dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can I calculate $\int_C{x^2}\:dy$ in which $C$ is a line segment from the point $(0,0)$ to $(3,2)$?

I am new to line integrals, I am only familiar when given a function and in $ds$. How can I do this?

Comment: Apply [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1379316/).

Comment: Yeah I noticed... and I said "Apply", not "Copy".

Comment: `Sonia` = `Yagna Patel`?

Comment: @Did No I never knew you could parametrize a line segment

Comment: I have a funny feeling of comments disappearing and precise questions being avoided... @Sonia: Do you operate with two accounts?

Comment: And now `Sonia` is `integrator`...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\int_C f(x,y) dy=\int_a^b f(x(t),y(t)) y'(t) dt$$

Parametrize your line segment and plug it in here and you have your answer.

Comment: @YagnaPatel For the $x$ part, it is $x(t)=3t$ for $0\leq t \leq 1$. What's it for $y(t)$?

Comment: @YagnaPatel You parametrize the _line_:
$$
\cases{x(t) = 3t\\y(t) = 2t}
$$
and then you note that the integration limits then become $\int_0^1 dt$, since $t = 0$ gives $(0,0)$ and $t = 1$ gives $(3, 2)$.

Comment: @Arthur Wow. never knew that